# Select rows from a dataframe, accounting for repeat values for a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following exemplar (for the problem) dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[91,2,33,41,56,78,910,331],'Score':[97,91,92,84,95.6,92,89,90]})
```

I have a function that is called with df1 as one of its arguments. Among other things, the function needs to return the first n (say, in this case 3) rows after sorting it on Score:

```
def sortandextract(df1,n1,...):
    ...
    df1.sort_values(by=['Score'], ascending=[False],inplace=True)
    df2=df1[:n1]
    ...
    return(df2,len(df2))
```

This function is called many times with different df1s (these dataframes have hundreds of rows). Sometimes, the scores are repeated (as above), other times they are not.

I want a pythonic method for returning n1+k rows (where k is the number of times the last score in the Score column is repeated). In the above example, I will have a problem if were to do a function call:

```
sortandextract(df1,3)
```

I would want this function call to return 4 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `rank`

```
n=3
ret=df1[df1.Score.rank(method='min',ascending=False)<=n]
   ID  Score
0  91   97.0
2  33   92.0
4  56   95.6
5  78   92.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I am uneasy about using .Score. Some of my column named have spaces in them. Is there a more robust way to do this?

Comment: @user2751530 just use `df1['Score']`.

Comment: Yes, @user2751530 it is wise to stick with just using the ['column name'] convention over  dot notation.